# Не удается найти элемент Selenium text()

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

Вот так пытаюсь найти:

```
   element = WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(
                        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, 
   "//div[text()='{}']".format("Все переменные существенные"))))
```

Но элемент не находит.

С заголовком вопроса спокойно находится:

```
   element = WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(
                        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, 
   "//span[text()='{}']".format("Вопрос 15"))))
```

[image: Html]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавьте пробелы как в html спереди и сзади, он ищет точное совпадение.
(" Все переменные существенные ")

Comment: Спасибо, в моем случае это были переходы на новую строку

Answer (score 0):

```py
xpath = "//div[contains(@text, '{}')]".format("Все переменные существенные")
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(
                        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, xpath)))
```

Comment: С какой целью вы ищете элемент по его тексту? Может вам CSS селекторы тут бы подошли, можно например все ответы найти вот так: `driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.answer > .answer_row > .answer_label')`

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]